# Use AppleScript to find the currently playing song (and other metadata)

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, audio, music

The audio section of the touch bar can automatically detect which app is playing audio, and adds media controls to play/pause, skip, and seek through any audio. As an example, this works for Quicktime, Spotify, and even YouTube audio from browsers like Google Chrome. How can I use AppleScript to mimic these functions? I want to get the name of the song, be able to play/pause, skip, and even seeking if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I made a cli tool that lets you read properties from the private `MediaRemote` framework.

https://github.com/kirtan-shah/nowplaying-cli

Since it uses private APIs, it may break with future macOS updates but is currently working on Ventura 13.1.

Here is an example that will retrieve the song name:
[image: now playing center screenshot]

[image: nowplaying-cli usage]

The tool also supports commands like play/pause:

```
nowplaying-cli play
```

If you want to call this from AppleScript you can use the following syntax:

```
do shell script "<your command>"
```

Comment: This is amazing -- thank you for your work on this! All other solutions to detect audio playing on OSX are dirty hacks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very useful tool and I have a recommendation on the best place to learn how to use AppleScript to interact with media.

- https://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php

This is 100% possible and you might even find the exact script you need, already written. Worst case, you can see the code and hopefully adapt one to your needs.

Comment: OP mentioned the general interface that was introduced in maybe 10.12+, not itunes specific. For that you can use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter). If you want to do from pure applescript, maybe use obj-c bridge?